# Find the antiderivative F (x) for each function f(x)

Tags: calculus, integration

$$f(x) = 8\sec x (\sec x - 4 \tan x)$$

Hi!

So I've already solved this but I just want to double check my answer. I got $8 (\tan(x) - 4\sec(x)) + C$ as my answer.

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check by taking the derivative:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(8(\tan x - 4\sec x)+C) = 8\sec^2 x - 32\sec x \tan x = 8\sec x(\sec x -  4\tan x) = f(x)$$

So, yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: You should always be able to check an antiderivative by differentiation + simplification; no need to ask MSE.